# How to merge remote-tracking a none github branch?

Tags: git, github

I would like to track a remote branch from Google opensource for a Pixel 3 kernel.

But unfortunately, google opensource is not in GitHub, so setting up the link to remote tracking is a bit harder to me (I'm still learning).

Basically, I would like to do like this kind of commit : https://github.com/flar2/Bluecross/commit/76f36cb421cc871d94f881febb2b7eca7ba3e574

Here is my `remote -v` actual response (modified a bit for confidentiality):

```
xxx@kernel:~$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/xxx/Liloo-P3-bluecross.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/xxx/Liloo-P3-bluecross.git (push)
upstream    https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-msm-bluecross-4.9-pie-qpr1 (fetch)
upstream    https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-msm-bluecross-4.9-pie-qpr1 (push)
xxx@kernel:~$
```

But when I try the following:

```
git fetch upstream
```

it returns:

```
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
```

I would like to keep updated from this upstream branch into my GitHub branch named for example `Liloo_P3`.

Any idea how to do that please?

Answer (score 2):

Git remotes should identify *repositories*, not branches. Your remote should be

```
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest
```

Then you can fetch the branch you want, e.g.

```
git fetch upstream android-msm-bluecross-4.9-pie-qpr1
```

From there it depends on what you want to do. Create a local branch from it if you want to work from there, merge it into your existing branch, etc.

If you just want to merge it into `Liloo_P3` you could do something like

```
git checkout Liloo_P3
git merge upstream/android-msm-bluecross-4.9-pie-qpr1
```